# Vector Variables vs Matrix Variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hı guys. I am a new programmer in Matlab.

But I have a problem.

Do i have to use curly brackets in vector variables? or Only parantheses are used in vector variables?

I want to define a vector variable which is called number.

```
  Number = [10^0,10^0.01 .... 10^1]
```

Do you have any idea?

I tried this command but it does not work.

```
  num=(e10:e0.1:e1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with brackets. What you need is the [element-wise power operator, `.^`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html):

```
num = 10.^(0:0.01:1)
```

I don't know where you saw syntax like `e10`, but it's not MATLAB.

The curly braces are only for cell arrays which you would use when storing variables of different types or size e.g.

```
arr = {'I am a string', 0.344, 7 + 3i, [1,2;3,4]}
```

Otherwise use square braces to concatenate matrices up to two dimensions and regular round parentheses to index matrices.

Comment: He probably tried use the syntax 1e0, 1e1, etc., that equal 1*10^0, 1*10^1, etc. Like the symbol in calculator.